# Make ajax call using jquery + asp.net core 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET CORE 2.0 MVC and JQUERY to performe a ajax call.

Follows my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public bool TemplateManagement(Template template)
    {
        try
        {
            template.version = template.version + 1;
            template.templateType = Template.TemplateType.MEDICAL_APPOINTMENT;
            //new TemplateDataMapper().ReplaceTemplate(template);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

My javascript code:

```
let data = {};
    data.ID = templateID;
    data.name = $("#formName").val();
    data.description = $("#formDescription").val();
    data.fields = [];
    data.version = parseInt($("#version").val());

    let tableFields = $(".table-fields");

    for (let i = 0; i < tableFields.length; i++) {
        data.fields.push({
            fieldDescription: $(tableFields[i]).find(".field-description input").val(),
            fieldType: {
                identifier: $(tableFields[i]).find(".field-type select option:selected").attr("type")
            }
        });
    }



    $.ajax({
        url: location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        accept: 'application/json',
        sucess: function (data) {
            alert('O template foi registado com sucesso');
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Um erro inexperado aconteceu. Por favor, tente mais tarde');
        }

    });
```

The server is hit by this call and perform the operations that it supposed to do, but it does not answer to the client (ajax call) with any sucess or error message. It is really strange.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you saying, your code is calling the alert in the `error` handler or `success` handler ?

Comment: @Shyju I'm saying the exact opposite, the alerts aren't be shown

Comment: so the ajax call never receives a response back ?

Comment: Sorry ! i meant  "not calling" :)

Comment: @Yes, it is really strange :S I'm not seeing anything wrong on my solution

Comment: Is this inside a form submit and page reloads? Also inspect xhr requests in browser dev tools netwrok and see what happens with your request

Comment: @charlietfl it is not inside of a form. I will check the xhr requests

Comment: @charlietfl I verified and i'm receiving the header as 200 status and I receive the boolean. It is for sure a problem with the way that I'm using the jqeury

Comment: Is the response body inside the request in dev tools valid json? have you tried commenting out the `location.reload()`?

Comment: If you want page to reload why use ajax at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159782/discussion-between-ricardo-rocha-and-charlietfl).